# how to handle one-to-many relationship in mysql in-clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have joined tables that looks something like this

t_joined:

```
  SELECT t1.name
       , t2.name
       , t3.name
    from t1
    join t2
      on t2.id = t1.id
  join t3
    on t3.id = t3.id
```

result looks like this

```
   t1.name   t2.name    t3.name
   James      Chris      Jessica
```

I want to return rows that have above names from 3 tables.
Trying this using where clause

```
select *
  from new_table
 where name in (SELECT t1.name
                     , t2.name
                     , t3.name
                  from t1
                  join t2
                    on t2.id = t1.id
                  join t3
                    on t3.id = t3.id)
```

This results in Error `Operand should contains 1 column(s)`.

So I've tried

```
select *
  from new_table
 where (name, name, name) in (SELECT t1.name
                     , t2.name
                     , t3.name
                  from t1
                  join t2
                    on t2.id = t1.id
                  join t3
                    on t3.id = t3.id)
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: consider posting some sample data

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Supposing that the "new_table" contains only a column "name" and then that you want to extract
   the rows with this "name" presents in all 3 tables:

with t1 as 
     (
       select '1' as id, 'James'   as name from dual union all
       select '2' as id, 'Chris'   as name from dual union all
       select '3' as id, 'Jessica' as name from dual 
     ),
     t2 as 
     (
       select '1' as id, 'Chris'   as name from dual union all
       select '2' as id, 'Paul'    as name from dual union all       
       select '3' as id, 'Jessica' as name from dual        
     ),
     t3 as 
     (
       select '1' as id, 'Jessica' as name from dual union all
       select '2' as id, 'Jessica' as name from dual union all
       select '3' as id, 'Jessica' as name from dual       
     ),
     new_table as
     (
       select 'Jessica' as name from dual union all
       select 'James'   as name from dual union all
       select 'Chris'   as name from dual 
     )
     select N.name
       from new_table N
      where exists (     
                     SELECT 1
                       from t1
                       join t2
                         on t2.id = t1.id
                       join t3
                         on t3.id = t1.id
                     where t1.name = N.name
                       and t2.name = N.name
                       and t3.name = N.name
                    );
                    
2) Instead If we supposing that the triple values rules and you want to extract the name of the "new_table" that have at least one name 
   in the triple values then:
   
with t1 as 
     (
       select '1' as id, 'James'   as name from dual union all
       select '2' as id, 'Chris'   as name from dual union all
       select '3' as id, 'Jessica' as name from dual 
     ),
     t2 as 
     (
       select '1' as id, 'Chris'   as name from dual union all
       select '2' as id, 'Paul'    as name from dual union all       
       select '3' as id, 'Jessica' as name from dual        
     ),
     t3 as 
     (
       select '1' as id, 'Jessica' as name from dual union all
       select '2' as id, 'Jessica' as name from dual union all
       select '3' as id, 'Jessica' as name from dual       
     ),
     new_table as
     (
       select 'Jessica' as name from dual union all
       select 'James'   as name from dual union all
       select 'Chris'   as name from dual 
     )
     select N.name
       from new_table N
      where exists (     
                     SELECT 1
                       from t1
                       join t2
                         on t2.id = t1.id
                       join t3
                         on t3.id = t1.id
                     where t1.name = N.name
                        or t2.name = N.name
                        or t3.name = N.name
                    );
                    
3) Else Please you specify better the description of the new_table and the meaning of one-to-many relationship

Thank you
```